# Using BLO on a Base Used for an Electrical Lamp

Tags: staining, boiled-linseed-oil, electrical-requirements

I'm just finishing a wooden lamp as a base for an electrical lamp (using a porcelain bulb socket)

Do I need to worry about the flammability of the stain/wood?
Assuming I keep the electrical components in a neat and unexposed.

This is my first ever wood working project so I'm rather clueless (even after using my best friend Google ;) )

Many Thanks!!

Comment: You may get better answers of on diy.SE, the site for home improvement, although you may not. I held off flagging for migration because I'm not sure. I'd wait and see if you get answers here, and if not, have it migrated.

Comment: Many many lamps made from wood, unless you were planning on doing anything atypical or unusual you shouldn't have a problem. Heat output is anyway very related to the type of bulb used. Incandescent bulbs give off much more heat than the two other likely alternatives, compact fluorescents (CFLs) and LED bulbs which is the reason they're so much less energy-efficient. But even with incandescents the bulb surface would have to be practically touching the wood for mild scorching to occur. FYI, we have a couple of previous Q&As that touch on using BLO if you need pointers on how to do that right.

Comment: Wanted to expand a bit on what I said about applying BLO right. Most guides to oiling online aren't great, and while you'll still get a 'finished look' it won't look as good as an oiled finish can look, which is very good indeed if you do it properly. The secret is not in the spacing of applications, it's not in flooding the surface with excess oil (something I don't recommend as it needlessly wastes oil) and it's not in thinning the oil to increase penetration (it doesn't), it is in *buffing the heck out of the wood after the oil goes on*. 75% of a good oil finish is in the buffing.

Comment: @Graphus if you could, please give a reference for a good article about the whole process. Also, maybe consider submitting a formal answer? (Even it it's out of the scope of this question, relating it to this question) :) Thanks!

Comment: I wish I could link you to a good article covering the whole process, but actually I can't think of one. To be quite honest I don't think I've ever read a really good how-to online about doing a traditional oiled finish, probably because so few people do it that way any more. But the basics are really just as simple as brief instructions suggest — wipe/rub oil onto the surface, wipe off the excess, repeat as often as your patience holds out. The only specific details that are almost always left out in modern guides are to wipe the surface absolutely dry and to rub *hard*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thete are lots of lamps out there with wooden bases with various finishes.If the wiring isn't bad, and the socket is approved for use in contact with wood (most are, if mounted correctly) and you let there be enough airflow around the bulb for it to cool itself, this really shouldn't be a problem.